# Pseudo rounded cube in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, lighting, mesh

If I have a cube in OpenGL, how can I have it appear like rounded?
 I think it's too complicated to really have the cube rounded so is there any "light trick" to have something like this:

[image]

The cubes in the image seem to be rounded on the top. The screenshot is from the game [Voxatron](https://voxatron.com)

Another view of the cubes (see how they seem rounded on the top):

[image]

Comment: "*The cubes in the image*" Um, what cubes? I just see some seemingly arbitrary colors.

Comment: Those look like colors baked into the textures.

Answer (score 3):

If silhouette is not important, you could bend the shading normal near edges.

Since it's a cube you can probably compute the normal procedurally in the shader based off of the uv. I.e. if uv is in range [0,0.1] or [0.9,1.0] start bending the normal towards horizontal.

If silhouette is important, drawing a rounded cube model with vertex normals would make the most sense. There are cube models which have the beveling to look like a rounded cube.